# Can $B\mathrm{Isom}(M,g)$ be viewed as the "moduli space of Riemannian metrics" on $M$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, classifying-spaces

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Pick some Riemannian metric $g_0$ on $M$,
and let $G := \mathrm{Isom}(M,g_0) \subset \mathrm{Diff}(M)$.

- Now, by classifying space theory, for a manifold $X$
  we have an equivalence of groupoids
  $$
  (\text{principal $G$-bundles on $X$})
  \simeq
  [X,BG] \,,
  $$
  where in the RHS this is the groupoid with objects maps $X\rightarrow BG$ and morphisms the homotopies between these.
- However, do we not also have an equivalence of groupoids
  $$
  (\text{principal $G$-bundles on $X$}) \simeq
  (\text{$M$-fiber bundles over $X$ equipped with fiberwise Riemannian metric})
  $$
  given in the forward direction by taking the associated bundle w.r.t. the $G$ action on $M$? (Analogously with how principal $O(n,\mathbb{R})$-bundles are equivalent to rank-$n$ real vector bundles with bundle metric.)
- Thus we should have an equivalence between $M$-fiber bundles on $X$ equipped with fiberwise Riemannian metric, and maps $X \rightarrow BG$, up to "coherent homotopy".
- In the case of $X = \mathrm{pt}$, an $M$-fiber bundle over a point with a fiberwise Riemannian metric, is just a choice of Riemannian metric on $M$.

  Thus the groupoid of Riemannian metrics on $M$ is equivalent to the groupoid $[\mathrm{pt},BG]$; more simply, the space of Riemannian metrics on $M$ is $BG$.

My first question is, do the steps above make sense? Especially the equivalence $$
(\text{principal $G$-bundles on $X$}) \simeq
(\text{$M$-fiber bundles over $X$ equipped with fiberwise Riemannian metric})
$$ in the 2nd bullet point?

---

Next, couldn't we also treat the space of Riemannian structures on $M$ as the space of lifts $\tilde{f} : M\rightarrow BO_m$ of $M$'s tangent bundle classifying map $M \rightarrow BGL_m$?

Is there some direct way to see how these two models of the "moduli space of Riemannian metrics" coincide?

Comment: The moduli space of Riemannian metrics on $M$ is contractible, so it's certainly not $B$ of any interesting topological group. $B$ of the isometry group is the "moduli space of Riemannian manifolds isometric to $M$" which is not the same thing.